# Strange console.log behavior

Tags: javascript

In next.js, `getInitialProps` can run on server or client. On client `ctx.req` is undefined. To get cookies i check this and log cookies. Problem is that `console.log` with initial string gives me error. I think i'm missing something here, but not sure what...

Error is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined

```
Test.getInitialProps = async (ctx: any): Promise<any> => {
  console.log(ctx.req ? ctx.req.headers.cookie : document.cookie) // works
  console.log('cookies:' + ctx.req ? ctx.req.headers.cookie : document.cookie) // error

  return { init: 1 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use a comma instead of a plus

Comment: Addition has a higher operator precedence than the ternary operator.  Put the ternary inside parenthesis if you want it evaluated first.

Comment: I don't think the arguments you think you're passing to `console.log` are the ones being passed. Inserting brackets to get the same functionality looks like `console.log(('cookies:' + ctx.req) ? ctx.req.headers.cookie : document.cookie);`. You've misjudged the order in which your operations resolve.

Comment: @Amy thanks, please answer so i can accept about ternary.

Comment: I believe the question should be reopened.  The error message was added shortly before it was closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What is happening and why

The issue is caused by [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence):  addition acts first (priority 14), before the ternary operator (priority 4).  A string is always truthy, so your condition is always true.

That is, with this expression:

```
'cookies:' + ctx.req ? ctx.req.headers.cookie : document.cookie
```

It will get evaluated into:

```
'cookies: [object object]' ? ctx.req.headers.cookie : document.cookie
```

The condition is always going to by truthy, which wasn't what you had intended.

#### Solution

You can either wrap the ternary inside parenthesis (priority 21), so it will be evaluated first, or just change the addition to a comma, thus supplying two arguments to `console.log`.  This is my preferred solution, but I present both:

```
console.log('cookies:', ctx.req ? ctx.req.headers.cookie : document.cookie);
```

OR

```
console.log('cookies:' + (ctx.req ? ctx.req.headers.cookie : document.cookie));
```

I prefer the first solution because it can log the cookie to the console as an object; the latter solution will coerce the cookie to a string, which may or may not give the desired results.